# Input and output power of ZVS not understood

Tags: zvs

I am trying to learn electronics and came across these ZVS drivers, which seem quite elementary. I understand what an inductor and a capacitor is (although obviously I don't know all the concepts). My questions is this: how can a ZVS driver heater with like an input of 12 V and 2-10 A (depending on what you put inside of the coil) output like 70 V and 30 A on the output?

Is there some kind of factor I am not seeing? Because otherwise how can one go from 120 W (12 * 10) to 2100 W (70 * 30).

This video of a well known engineer does not explain this 'gain' of power other than just saying it is reactive power (oscillation). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFJeIt_JcEc

Just a simple explanation or a link would make me very happy :)

Comment: Each cycle you're putting some fraction of 120W into a resonant circuit, As very little energy is taken out, it accumulates exactly like gentle pushes of a pendulum or child's swing build up to a large amplitude. There isn't 2100W available : there's 70V at the voltage peaks (no current; all the charge is in the capacitor) or 30A at the zero voltage points (all the energy is in the inductor). When the *losses* such as I^2*R reach 120W the amplitude stops increasing.

Comment: it sounds like 'free energy', which is of course non sense...

Comment: but it does sound like the answer i was expecting, still difficult to 'feel'